# Who discovered Bremsstrahlung?

Tags: physics, discoveries, electromagnetism, radiation

I found a [web page](https://www.school-for-champions.com/science/x-ray_generation.htm) that says that it was discovered by Tesla in 1890, is that true or generally acknowledged?

Isn't 1890 too early a date?

Answer (score 3):

See listing here:
[Index of Early Bremsstrahlung Articles](http://shadetreephysics.com/bremindx.htm)

The earliest items are: patents filed by Tesla in 1891 and 1892.  And papers (by others, not Tesla) in *Philosophical Magazine* in 1891.

Answer (score 0):

The term Bremsstrahlung is said to be coined by Arnold Sommerfeld in 1909. Cannot access this chapter but the abstract is available. It must have the original reference.
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-70626-7_23

Comment: +1. The quoted paper of Sommerfeld is ([1909](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?41.0951.03), [p. 974](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=mdp.39015023919049&num=974)). Müller–Pouillets Lehrbuch ([1914](//books.google.com/books?id=09xUYllHd5kC&pg=PA1080&dq=Bremsstrahlung), pp. 956, 1080–1081) traces the concept before him to Wiechert, Stokes, J. J. Thomson, Heaviside, Abraham. (No mention of Tesla there, but 1894 work of his is mentioned at [X-rays](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray#Pre-R%C3%B6ntgen_observations_and_research).)

Comment: I never understood why 19th-century papers were typically long? I guess there was no pressure to publish more in those good times.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by “typically long”? That they didn’t slice them into [MPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_publishable_unit)s?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The modern trend is to write short articles but articles from 1920-1930s are typically 20-25 pages. I am sure about mathematics but chemistry editors usually return the paper for condensing.

Comment: Well, Tesla for one didn’t [overpublish](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/jfmen/MATH/JFM/quick.html?type=html&au=Tesla). Attributions to him at “shadetreephysics.com” or “school-for-champions.com” sound like a more recent cult (i.e., to answer the question, historically *not* influential or “generally acknowledged”).

Comment: I agree, people have started posing Tesla as a cult, who knew everything...just like the mysteries of the construction of Egyptian pyramids.

Comment: But the question is not about the word itself but rather discovery of the phenomenon, which pretty clearly dates back to Tesla.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That may be true, but I wouldn’t call the evidence given so far (two web pages) “pretty clear” that [Tesla](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla#X-ray_experimentation) was aware of *Bremsstrahlung* before e.g. [Röntgen](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_tube#The_discovery_of_X-rays) or the physicists quoted in Müller–Pouillet. What else is there?